# Is there a way to detect memory leaks for Go programs using cgo on Windows

Tags: windows, memory-leaks, go, cgo

I'm using cgo to link to C libraries or to use C code in my Go projects and I was wondering if there's a way to detect memory leaks on Windows.

Comment: Existing tools that instrument the C libraries should work in theory. Have you tried anything?

Comment: Valgrind doesn't seems to be supported. See https://github.com/golang/go/issues/782

It also seems that pprof and Valgrind can't help. See slide at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ydWFpcoYraU#t=1105

Comment: yes, that's why I specified tools that *instrument* the C code (plus, valgrind doesn't support windows). On Linux, I've done things like use a custom allocator like tcmalloc in place of malloc for it's debugging features.